# adding values and merging json objects based on key in d3js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, nested-loops

I have a variable that looks something like this when I do console.log(variable1).

```
    0: {node01: "site05", amount: 1010}
    1: {node01: "site02", amount: 1200}
    2: {node01: "site08", amount: 880}
    3: {node01: "site04", amount: 870}
    4: {node01: "site01", amount: 650}
    5: {node01: "site06", amount: 1370}
    6: {node01: "site07", amount: 100}
    7: {node01: "site09", amount: 210}
    8: {node01: "site10", amount: 340}
```

Another variable which looks like this in console.log(variable2):

```
    0: {node02: "site08", amount: 100}
    1: {node02: "site02", amount: 200}
    2: {node02: "site03", amount: 1050}
    3: {node02: "site07", amount: 1300}
    4: {node02: "site09", amount: 850}
    5: {node02: "site10", amount: 890}
    6: {node02: "site04", amount: 640}
    7: {node02: "site06", amount: 290}
    8: {node02: "site01", amount: 50}
    9: {node02: "site05", amount: 200}
    10: {node02: "site11", amount: 1060}
```

I want to add the amount of both the variables based on the node value
for example, 
"node01": "site05" has amount:1010 and "node02": "site05" has amount:200
the resultant variable should have "node":"site05" amount:1210. Also, "site11" doesn't exist in variable1. so it should just have the value "node":"site11" amount:1060 --> this comes only from variable2

I tried using two nested for loops but it just results in nodes available in one variable. 
I am not sure how to map them all. 
Also, is there a solution using only d3js without using the for loops native to js? as from my understanding, D3 has some other approach to looping

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll probably want to prepare your data and then send the consolidated result to D3. For example:

```js
 const list1 = [
   {node01: "site05", amount: 1010},
   {node01: "site02", amount: 1200},
   {node01: "site08", amount: 880},
   {node01: "site04", amount: 870},
   {node01: "site01", amount: 650},
   {node01: "site06", amount: 1370},
   {node01: "site07", amount: 100},
   {node01: "site09", amount: 210},
   {node01: "site10", amount: 340},
];
const list2 = [
    {node02: "site08", amount: 100},
    {node02: "site02", amount: 200},
    {node02: "site03", amount: 1050},
    {node02: "site07", amount: 1300},
    {node02: "site09", amount: 850},
    {node02: "site10", amount: 890},
    {node02: "site04", amount: 640},
    {node02: "site06", amount: 290},
    {node02: "site01", amount: 50},
    {node02: "site05", amount: 200},
    {node02: "site11", amount: 1060},
];

const combinedList = [
  ...list1,
  ...list2,
];

const output = Object.values(combinedList.reduce((a, c) => {
  const node = Object.values(c).find(v => typeof v === 'string');
  a[node] = a[node] || {node, amount: 0};
  a[node].amount += c.amount;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it works!! Although, I don't quite understand why the last {} is necessary in the reduce function? I've tried removing it and the output isn't what it should be. But i don't understand how it effects the result. It would be great if you could explain that.

Comment: Sure thing. So `reduce` takes 2 arguments. 1) A reducer function and 2) A starting value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce. In this case, we build up an object using the node names as keys. So the first time into the loop, I want to have an EMPTY OBJECT to start filling up. So that `{}` is just the first value passed to accumulator parameter of the reduce function. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. just out of curiosity, what if i have more than two elements in the json object? something like {"node01":"site01", "node02":"site02", amount:100}? I tried this edit with the above code but it seems to loop through only node01

Comment: You'd have to change the 3 lines inside the reduce function to be a loop over all string values instead of just the first string value it finds. I used "string value" as the heuristic to find "node names", depending on what your data looks like, you may need to use a different heuristic (e.g. key prefix is "node" or similar).